# REST service that checks complex list

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to write a REST service with JAX-RS that consumes a list of modules in the form

```json
[
    {
        "name": "IRGENDWAS.TLK",
        "version": "020",
        "bibliothek": "asdf"
    },
    {
        "name": "IRGENDWAS2.TLK",
        "version": "030",
        "bibliothek": "asdf"
    },
    {
        "name": "XIRGENDWAS2.TLK",
        "version": "030",
        "bibliothek": "asdf"
    }
]
```

and checks their existence, returning something like

```json
[
    {
        "name": "IRGENDWAS.TLK",
        "version": "020",
        "bibliothek": "asdf",
        "existence": true
    },
    {
        "name": "IRGENDWAS2.TLK",
        "version": "030",
        "bibliothek": "asdf",
        "existence": true
    },
    {
        "name": "XIRGENDWAS2.TLK",
        "version": "030",
        "bibliothek": "asdf",
        "existence": false
    }
]
```

My best try so fat looks like this

```java
  @POST
  @Path("/bs2-existence-check")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Bs2ModulExistence> bs2ExistenceCheck(String modulListe)
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> nameList = JsonPath.parse(modulListe)
        .read("$.[*].name", List.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> versionList = JsonPath.parse(modulListe)
        .read("$.[*].version", List.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> bibliothekList = JsonPath.parse(modulListe)
        .read("$.[*].bibliothek", List.class);

    List<Bs2ModulExistence> backList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
    {
      String name = nameList.get(i);

      String version = versionList.get(i);

      String bibliothek = bibliothekList.get(i);

      boolean existence = checkExistence(name, version, bibliothek);

      Bs2ModulExistence bs2ModulExistence =
          new Bs2ModulExistence(name, version, bibliothek, existence);

      backList.add(bs2ModulExistence);

    }

    return backList;

  }
```

I guess that my usage of JsonPath is unnecessary here and I can just map this somehow directly. Furthermore, I don't know whether this should be a POST request.

Probably someone can tell me how to do this correctly.

Comment: https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: Why don't you just call the class Bs2Module and accept a List<Bs2Module> as a method parameter and just set the existence on the same objects and return the same list. If you already have POJO support on _serialization_ then you should also have _deserialization_ support to be able to accept the list of POJOs as a method parameter. Just make sure you have a no-arg constructor on the POJO class and that you have setters for all the fields.

Comment: I have tried that but deserialization failed. I guess I cannot just use a `List` with a self-created class. Probably I need to define somehow how the JSON should be deserialized.

Comment: What's happening? Are you getting some errors? If you are, can you post it, along with your POJO class and the dependencies you're using.

Comment: Ok, I tried again and now it works. Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

in order for your service to automatically marshal and unmarshal Java Objets to and from Json you have to specify a special parameter to your Jersey serlvet configuration (obviously this will be in the web.xml file). This parameter is com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature and will basically integrate Jersey with Jackson.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Create a POJO Module with attributes  "name","version","bibliothek", "existence"

and try change your method to :

```java
  @POST
  @Path("/bs2-existence-check")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Bs2ModulExistence> bs2ExistenceCheck(List<Module> modulListe)
```

after you can iterate through moduleListe to check an update existance

```java
return moduleListe.stream().map(m -> {
    boolean existence = checkExistence(m.name, m.version, m.bibliothek);
    m.existance  = existence;
    return m;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it did not need to set the `init-param`.